# Recursive Factorial

Tags: objective-c

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Factorial : NSObject 
+(int) factorial:(int) n;
@end

@implementation Factorial

+(int) factorial:(int)n
{
    if (n==0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return [self factorial:n]*[self factorial:n-1];
    }
}

@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i = [Factorial factorial:5];
    NSLog(@"%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

what is the problem with this code?? i am new in objective-c (i am from c background)
Or, i am getting wrong concept about objective c??

```
(Compiler generating ..)
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Mon Aug  8 20:32:45 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys002
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
[Switching to process 1413 thread 0x0]
warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.
(gdb)
```

and getting stuck at line +(int) factorial:(int) n   at the @implementation  resulting EXC_BAD_ACESS.

Thanks

Comment: What is the compiler telling you?

Comment: You tell us what the problem is, and we'll help you fix it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with ObjC, but lines:

```
+(int) factorial:(int)n
    //...
    return [self factorial:n]*[self factorial:n-1];
    //                      ^
```

look suspicious for me. It means that for n != 0 you will get endless recursion and face stack overflow :-)

Comment: should be like this.. .. return n* [self factorial:n-1];

Comment: BTW, it would be more space-efficent, if you change implementation to use tail call.

Answer (score 2):

You want to calculate `factorial:n`, but in your function use the result of `factorial:n`.

change:
`return [self factorial:n]*[self factorial:n-1];`

to:
`return n*[self factorial:n-1];`

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your code

```
return n*[self factorial:n-1];
```

to be

```
return  n* (n != 1 ? [self factorial:n-1] : 1);
```

The first one will make an infinite loop

For example:

```
int factorial = [self factorial:3];
NSLog(@"factorial 3 >> %i",factorial); the result is "factorial 3 >> 6"
```